# c# Check if there is a file on server with specific name

Tags: c#, installation

I making a program and wanted to make an update function... So lets say I make one update and put it on my dropbox.. When someone click on update, the program will check if there any file with different name (no same version) on the server and if there is, then start to download it.. Is it possible?

And my second problem I installed my program on my computer but when start the installer again it says:

*Another version of this product is already installed. Installation cof this version cannot continue. To configure or remove the existing version of this product use add/remove programs on the control panel.*

I want when I run second time installer a confirmation message appear if he want to delete previous version to install this one (I need this for the update)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a web service that provides an index / manifest of a directory that you want to synchronize.  The web service could also provide methods for uploading and downloading the synchronized files and folders.

If you are using a Visual Studio Setup Project (.msi) you can simply change the installer version.  Visual Studio sees the change and asks you if you want to change the product code. You would say 'yes'.  The installer should then remove previous versions before installing the latest. You would also want DetectNewerInstalledVersion = true and RemovePreviousVersions = true.

Not sure if it works for this scenario but you may want to look at a ClickOnce deployment.  It may solve both of your problems. [ClickOnce Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227123%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)